# Selecting different rows of 3D Tensor based on indices in another tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

Let's say there's a 3D Tensor:

```py
data = tensor([[[ 1,  2,  3],
                [ 4,  5,  6],
                [ 7,  8,  9]],

               [[10, 11, 12],
                [13, 14, 15],
                [16, 17, 18]]])
```

There is another tensor which has indices of the corresponding rows to be selected:

```py
idx = tensor([[2, 0],
              [1, 2]])
```

Is there a way to select `idx[i]` rows from the `i`th entry of `data`?
For the above example, the expected output is:

```py
tensor([[[ 7,  8,  9]
         [ 1,  2,  3]],

        [[13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18]]])
```

I tried using `data.gather(1, idx)` but that says

```bash
RuntimeError: Index tensor must have the same number of dimensions as input tensor
```